# Named range in combo box

Tags: excel, vba

How to insert a named range in combo box using VBA
Here according to value in combobox1 i need to insert certain named ranges in combobox2.
Here Def1m, Def2m etc are the named ranges

```
Private Sub Def_Change()
If combobox1.Value = "1 month" Then
Me.combobox2.RowSource = Def1m
ElseIf combobox1.Value = "2 month" Then
Me.combobox2.RowSource = Def2m
ElseIf combobox1.Value = "3 month" Then
Me.combobox2.RowSource = Def3m
ElseIf combobox1.Value = "6 month" Then
Me.combobox2.RowSource = Def6m
ElseIf combobox1.Value = "yearly" Then
Me.combobox2.RowSource = Defyearly
End If
End Sub
```

Please suggest

Comment: Is Def1m a variable or the name of the named range? If a string then put in "" e.g.  "Def1m"

Answer (score 1):

When writing strings to properties, you need to wrap the data in quotes, so to set the RowSource to Def1m you would send "Def1m" (as a string).

Also, you'd be much better off tackling this with a `Select Case` statement to make it tidy:

```
Private Sub Def_Change()
    With Me.combobox2
        Select Case combobox1.Value
            Case "1 month": .RowSource = "Def1m"
            Case "2 month": .RowSource = "Def2m"
            Case "3 month": .RowSource = "Def3m"
            Case "6 month": .RowSource = "Def6m"
            Case "yearly": .RowSource = "Defyearly"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @AravindSR - what is not working? If it is some type of runtime error, try changing  `"Def1m"` to `[Def1m]`, thus return a range and not a string. Like this - `Set .RowSource = [Def1m]`.

Comment: i did it but the value is not appearing in combo box 2

Comment: Do you mean the drop-down doesn't pre-populate with the first option? I think that's normal. You can set it using `Combobox2.ListIndex = 0`. I think zero (`0`) is the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function, taking the string from `combobox1` and returning a range. Thus, you would be able to call the function like this:

`Me.combobox2.RowSource = GetRowSource(combobox1.Value)`

and the whole logic would be somehow neat:

```
Sub TestMe()    
    Debug.Print GetRowSource("2 month").Address 'prints the address of named range "Def2m"
End Sub

Public Function GetRowSource(timePeriod As String) As Range    
    Select Case timePeriod
        Case "1 month"
            Set GetRowSource = [Def1m]
        Case "2 month"
            Set GetRowSource = [Def2m]
        Case "3 month"
            Set GetRowSource = [Def3m]
        Case "6 month"
            Set GetRowSource = [Def6m]
        Case "yearly"
            Set GetRowSource = [Defyearly]
        Case Else
            Set GetRowSource = Nothing
    End Select    
End Function
```